# How can I fix my particle board round kitchen table, I dropped it on its side and hole removing it from the box on concrete!

Tags: repair, kitchens, table, particle-board

I received my brand new round particle board kitchen table and decided to remove it from the box outside before lugging it up the stairs. I lost my grip and dropped it on the side on concrete and broke/bubbled up a portion of the round edge. I know I know, I regretted all of my decisions at this point. It has a glossy grey paint finish. I’m okay with changing that if need be, but I’m not quite sure how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Pictures will help seeing the damage.  If just the edging, possible to glue it back, or cut it off and replace.  If the wood it will be more work.

Comment: If you paid for it with a credit card, check for "purchase protection" coverage by the card. Quoting from bankrate.com, "Typically, credit card purchase protection applies to purchases you make with your credit card for a specific amount of time. With this important coverage, you can be reimbursed for an item or receive a replacement if your purchase is damaged or stolen, usually within 90 to 120 days."

Comment: At the worst, the damaged edge could be sliced off, and edging tape applied, leaving a flat edge to abut a wall. It would be a unique table, taking up a bit less room.